GORM fails to query boolean json field in MySQL
NOTE: I have only tested this issue with MySQL.
When querying a property inside a json field with a bool argument, the query returns 0 rows. However, if you embed the bool into the where clause itself, you get 1 row. The strange thing is that the generated SQL shown by the debugger is identical.
The results below are of type []Account:
type Account struct {
    gorm.Model
    UserID sql.NullInt64
    Number string
    Config AccountConfig `gorm:"type:json;serializer:json"`
}

type AccountConfig struct {
    Enabled bool   `json:"enabled"`
    Foo     string `json:"foo"`
    Bar     int64  `json:"bar"`
}

Broken Example:
DB.Where("config->'enabled' = ?", true).Find(&results)

2024/04/30 11:20:10 /__REDACTED__/playground/main_test.go:108
[0.847ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE config->'$.enabled' = true

Working Example:
DB.Where("config->'enabled' = true").Find(&results)

2024/04/30 11:20:10 /__REDACTED__/playground/main_test.go:108
[0.647ms] [rows:1] SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE config->'$.enabled' = true

I tried testing a variety of other variations as well, like using json_extract and the double arrow syntax, like config->>'$.enabled'. The same thing also happens with nested values, such as config->'$.foo.enabled' = true.
Also, see my issue on github in the GORM repo. I provided a range of test cases in my pull request linked in the issue.

In MySQL, a boolean field in a JSON document is returned either as a scalar JSON document or a scalar string value. You can see this with the mysql client with the --column-type-info option:
$ mysql --column-type-info

Using -> returns a JSON document, even though that JSON document consists of only a single scalar value.
mysql> select config->'$.enabled' from Accounts;
Field   1:  `config->'$.enabled'`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       JSON
Collation:  utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (255)
Length:     4294967292
Max_length: 4
Decimals:   31
Flags:      BINARY 

+---------------------+
| config->'$.enabled' |
+---------------------+
| true                |
+---------------------+

Using ->> returns an "unquoted" value, which turns the JSON value into a binary string.
mysql> select config->>'$.enabled' from Accounts;
Field   1:  `config->>'$.enabled'`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONG_BLOB
Collation:  utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (255)
Length:     4294967295
Max_length: 4
Decimals:   31
Flags:      BINARY 

+----------------------+
| config->>'$.enabled' |
+----------------------+
| true                 |
+----------------------+

Either way, the result of extracting a boolean from JSON does not yield an SQL boolean value, so it won't be comparable to true or a Go boolean true.
I got it to work this way:
db.Where("config->>'$.enabled' = ?", "true").Find(&results)

I'm passing the Go string value "true", which will compare to the SQL binary string 'true' returned from the JSON extract operator.
I would strongly recommend you use normal columns instead of JSON. There is little advantage to using JSON, and it introduces a lot of weird complexity like this case.

Thank you for the explanation, this definitely helps. My solution for the time being is what you suggested (compare to the string value instead). It's just so strange to me that the query works in one case but not the other. The SQL from the debugger looks identical and when running the SQL directly in the database it works as expected. I actually started by writing the SQL out by hand and testing in the database and then brought that knowledge over to GORM after, only to find that it didn't work as expected.

Seems to me more like an issue with GORM doing something weird behind the scenes and either not rendering the SQL in the debugger log accurately or dropping the result somehow and just saying 0 rows were returned.
